# How would you solve these similar logic problems?

Tags: logic

I'm not sure how to derive the conclusion from this problem

1. (x)(Ax ⊃ Bx)
2. Am & An      / Bm & Bn

As well as a similar problem with a disjunction instead of a conjunction

1. (x)(Ax ⊃ Bx)
2. Am v An      / Bm v Bn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some review I came up with this:

1. (x)(Ax ⊃ Bx)
2. Am • An / Bm • Bn
3. Am ⊃ Bm ........... 1, UI
4. Am ..................... 2, Simp
5. Bm ..................... 3, 4, MP
6. An ⊃ Bn ............ 1, UI
7. An • Am ............ 2, Com
8. An ..................... 7, Simp
9. Bn ..................... 6, 8, MP
10. Bm • Bn ............ 5, 9, Conj

And the answer to the 2nd one

1. (x)(Ax ⊃ Bx)
2. Am v An      / Bm v Bn
3. Am ⊃ Bm ......... 1, UI
4. An ⊃ Bn ........... 1, UI
5. Bm ∨ Bn .......... 2, 3, 4 CD

Comment: It's good; you can delete step 7 because you have it already in 2 and you can derive 8 by 2,Simp ...